# Procedure to encrypt worklight properties file in mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, windows-server-2012

I have created mobilefirst 7.1 project and enabled operational MF analytics for that. For that I have configured mf analytics url and credencialin worklight properties. I want to encrypt credential.

```
wl.analytics.url=http://{{ip}}:{{port}}/analytics-service/data
wl.analytics.console.url=http://{{ip}}:{{port}}/analytics/console
wl.analytics.username={{username}}
wl.analytics.password={{password}}
```

Here 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_storing_properties_in_encrypted_format.html

I found I can do it using encrypt.bat utility on windows server.

But I don't how to pass file as input to bat file and get encrypted file as output. Is there link from where I can get steps to encrypt properties file?

I knoe JNDI is a another option but I want this specific.

Server OS : Windows 2012 Sever R2

Comment: Look into using JNDI properties in your application server.

Comment: Thanks Idan, JNDI is an option. But I want know procedure of encrypting properties file.

Comment: The JNDI path still uses the properties files. They are just not defined in it.

Comment: You mean to say, I can remove this properties from workligh console. And then after deployment, I can manually add these properties here in WAS ND : Enterprise Applications > IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_myapp > Environment entries for Web modules

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with batch file. Why did you steal my money making me look at it. .

Comment: Now I forgot the batch file but I am not so much aware about JNDI.
Can I do this --> I can remove this properties from workligh console. And then after deployment, I can manually add these properties here in WAS ND : Enterprise Applications > IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_myapp > Environment entries for Web modules

Comment: What I want is, I don't wat these properties exposed in worklight.properties

Comment: At minimum you must have the properties defined in the worklight.properties file. The values are stored as JNDI properties and are encrypted by the application server.